# Capture Oracle Errors in a Manually Created Table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hi I want to capture all the Oracle Errors for my DML operations in the manually created table with columns as `ErrorID` and `Error_Descr`. 
How to get `ORA_ERR_NUMBER$` and `ORA_ERR_MESG$`  values in the above columns?
This table contains user defined errors as well so I do not want to limit it to the Oracle Errors.

Is there any way of capturing Oracle as well as User Defined Errors in the User Defined Tables?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation [**Link**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables004.htm#CJABHICH),

Oracle allows you to use a manually created table for `LOGGING` only if you have included these mandatory columns.

```
ORA_ERR_NUMBER$
ORA_ERR_MESG$
ORA_ERR_ROWID$
ORA_ERR_OPTYP$
ORA_ERR_TAG$
```

If you want other columns to capture the information in those two columns, you could make them as virtual columns.

```
CREATE TABLE my_log_table (
    ORA_ERR_NUMBER$ NUMBER
    ,ORA_ERR_MESG$ VARCHAR2(2000)
    ,ORA_ERR_ROWID$ ROWID
    ,ORA_ERR_OPTYP$ VARCHAR2(2)
    ,ORA_ERR_TAG$ VARCHAR2(2000)
    ,ErrorID NUMBER AS (COALESCE(ORA_ERR_NUMBER$, ORA_ERR_NUMBER$))
    ,Error_Descr VARCHAR2(2000) AS (COALESCE(ORA_ERR_MESG$, ORA_ERR_MESG$))
    );
```

using `COALESCE` is a hack because Oracle doesn't allow you to have one column default to another directly.

Now, you could run your error logging dml normally mentioning the logging table name.

```
INSERT INTO t_emp
SELECT employee_id * 10000
    ,first_name
    ,last_name
    ,hire_date
    ,salary
    ,department_id
FROM hr.employees
WHERE salary > 10000 LOG ERRORS
INTO my_log_table('ERR_SAL_LOAD') REJECT LIMIT 25

0 row(s) inserted.

select ORA_ERR_TAG$,ErrorID,Error_Descr FROM my_log_table ;

ORA_ERR_TAG$    ERRORID ERROR_DESCR
ERR_SAL_LOAD    1438    ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
ERR_SAL_LOAD    1438    ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```